# How to get the filename from a given UIImage object?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

How to get the filename from a given UIImage object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't, since you can construct a `UIImage` from pure data without a file.

Answer (score 1):

UIImage does not store the file name it was loaded from. You need to save it separately somewhere on download for future usage.